# Angular 4 - update route without appending another outlet's route to URL

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a situation in `Angular 4.0.3` where I have two `<router-outlet>`'s on a page.

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="nav"></router-outlet>
```

The first outlet will accept routes for content, and the second will accept routes for navigation. I achieve the navigation using this;

```
router.navigate(['', {outlets: { nav: [route] } }],{skipLocationChange: true });
```

This changes the outlet's contents without updating the URL - since I don't want any `url` that look like .. `(nav:user)`.

The problem is the remaining outlet. I do want the URL to update when those are clicked, for instance ...

```
.../user/profile
```

Functionally, I can get both outlets to have the proper content, but it keeps appending the `nav` outlet's route to the url, like this ...

```
.../user/profile(nav:user)
```

Is there any way I can stop it from adding the `(nav:user)` part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless there is some trick I'm not aware of ... I don't think you can. The address bar is what maintains the route state. So without the secondary outlet information in the address bar, the router won't know how to keep the correct routed component in the secondary outlet.

You could try overriding the `navigateByUrl` method as shown here: http://plnkr.co/edit/78Hp5OcEzN1jj2N20XHT?p=preview

```
export class AppModule {   constructor(router: Router) {
    const navigateByUrl = router.navigateByUrl;

    router.navigateByUrl = function(url: string|UrlTree, extras: NavigationExtras = {skipLocationChange: false}): Promise<boolean> {
      return navigateByUrl.call(router, url, { ...extras, skipLocationChange: true });
    }   } }
```

You could potentially add logic here then to check which routes you need to do this on.

Comment: Can I prevent the state of the desired outlet from changing then? Perhaps that would achieve the effect?

Comment: Without changing the state, how would you route? Maybe I don't understand your question or what you are trying to achieve. Can you do a plunker?

Comment: The named outlet should only change if the user explicitly clicks a navigation link. It should not be tied to the url - I'm using `skipLocationChange` on it to keep the url unchanged when they jump around the navigation.

Comment: The named outlet is a sidebar. I'll try to make a plunkr, it's just a big app at this point.

Comment: I tried adding the `{ skipLocationChange: true }` to my secondary route and it worked to hide the route. But only until I routed to something else in the primary route. I spoke with someone that knows a lot about routing and he said that you can add the `{ skipLocationChange: true }` to all of the routes and then you should be able to hide all of the Url changes.

Comment: Right, but I only want to hide the routes for the sidebar navigation.